# Stopwatch - Start from a custom date in the past

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nstimer, stopwatch

I am new to programming and am just looking to be pointed in the right direction.

I want to create a stopwatch that will show you time elapsed since a custom date that the user has input. I am assuming I will use NSTimer and/or NSDate to complete this - but what should I look into for allowing the user to input their own start date?

Example: The user wants to know how long they haven't slept for - They input the time they last woke up and the timer displays to them how long they have been awake.

Much appreciated

Comment: Sorry I meant `UIDatePicker`. Read its [class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html), and also the [iOS View Controller programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/viewcontrollerpgforiphoneos/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH1-SW1), for guidance on how to integrate them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSDate's -timeIntervalSinceDate: to get the elapsed time in seconds

For example:

```
NSDate *date1 = // date the user woke up
NSTimeInterval timeAwake = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:date1]; // time awake in seconds
```

[Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/timeIntervalSinceDate%3a)

Comment: Thanks for the help! Building on your code... 
Can I use the following to grab the date from UIDatePicker?

NSDate *date = [self.datePicker date];